# How to Display Different CNN Activations using Keract?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Recently I have been working with CNNs for about a month now and I am trying to use **Keract** to visualize the activations for each layer of a CNN given one image:

```py
from keras import activations
from keract import get_activations, display_heatmaps, display_activations

keract_inputs = x_test[:1]
keract_targets = y_test[:0]
activations = get_activations(model, keract_inputs)
display_activations(activations=activations,cmap='YlGnBu')
```

OUTPUT:

[**Activations**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0E59.png)

Yet this code only displays the **SECOND** image and when I try to change the code so that this shows me the first image or the later images, it skips the layers every time:

```py
from keras import activations
from keract import get_activations, display_heatmaps, display_activations

keract_inputs = x_test[:2]
keract_targets = y_test[:0]
activations = get_activations(model, keract_inputs)
display_activations(activations=activations,cmap='YlGnBu')
```

OUTPUT:

```
input_1 (32, 32, 3) -> Skipped. First dimension is not 1.
conv2d (2, 32, 32, 32) -> Skipped. First dimension is not 1.
conv2d_1 (2, 30, 30, 32) -> Skipped. First dimension is not 1.
max_pooling2d (2, 15, 15, 32) -> Skipped. First dimension is not 1.
conv2d_2 (2, 15, 15, 64) -> Skipped. First dimension is not 1.
conv2d_3 (2, 13, 13, 64) -> Skipped. First dimension is not 1.
max_pooling2d_1 (2, 6, 6, 64) -> Skipped. First dimension is not 1.
flatten (2, 2304) -> Skipped. First dimension is not 1.
dense (2, 512) -> Skipped. First dimension is not 1.
dense_1 (2, 10) -> Skipped. First dimension is not 1.
```

Any way I can change my code so that it displays the activations for other images?

Answer (score 1):

Found the Solution:
Telling the program to set `keract_inputs = x_test[:2]` actually gives 2 dimensions from the first element to the second element, but if you change this to another 1 dimensional range, the program works perfectly

```py
from keras import activations
from keract import get_activations, display_heatmaps, display_activations

keract_inputs = x_test[1:2]
keract_targets = y_test[:0]
activations = get_activations(model, keract_inputs)
display_activations(activations=activations,cmap='YlGnBu')
```

You have to define the range between the element you want and the one before it

This works when trying to find activations for image `N` by selecting `x_test[N-1:N]`